# which neural network is good for predecting the value of strings

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, strings

I have a dataset that contains some strings. A numeric value is assigned to each string.
I want to develop a machine learning (deep learning) model to get a string and predict its value.
What neural network do you suggest for this model? Should I use RNN (LSTM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the strings are variable-length, a recurrent neural network would be a reasonable choice: either a LSTM or a convolutional network.